# Simulate a click from <button> on <asp:button>

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I am trying to simulate a click from #btn_new_login to #btn_login. So when the user click #btn_new_login, it will simulate a click on #btn_login as well.

```
<button id="btn_new_login" onclick="document.getElementById('btn_login').click();">Login</button>

<asp:Button ID="btn_login" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClientClick="return checkfields()" OnClick="btn_login_Click" />
```

Comment: check the return value of checkfields method. It should return true for page submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_new_login').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + '<%=btn_login.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Try this code. This should work if your `checkfields` method is returning true.

Comment: did you remove onclick attribute of btn_new_login button? Also check what value the method checkfields is returning.

Comment: what about the return value of checkfields method?

Comment: you have defined attribute OnClientClick="return checkfields()" for btn_login button. This will execute checkfields method on client side whenever btn_Login is clicked. If this method returns false, page will not submit. For once just remove this attribute and try,

Comment: Please check the value of checkfields methods through debugging in browser

Comment: btn_login.Attributes.Add("onclick","return checkfields();"); Put this code in your Page_Load event of your .aspx page. Remove the OnClientClick attrubute

Comment: Adding it on Page_Load will makes it not works again.

Comment: The only way to make it works is not putting checkfields();

Comment: I got it working with ClientClick attibute. Just wrap the onclick event binding code in document.ready. Modified my answer. Please check.

Comment: It's still the same. Not putting onClientClick works. But putting will not work

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger via [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

```
$('#btn_new_login').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('button').trigger('click');
});
```

remove the onclick attributes

Comment: what do you mean by **not able to get it works** do you have errors in the console??

Comment: No errors. It just does not load the code behind of #btn_login which I have set breakpoints

Comment: from what i in the javascript debugger you can't create breakpoints,what debugger are you using

Comment: I am using Visual Studio. I have breakpoints on code behind. So when #btn_login get click, it will load the its code behind

Comment: does Visual Studio have a javascript debugger?, check that out

Comment: Nope, it does not have it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would need to get the `client id` since its an `asp:button`

```
<button id="btn_new_login" onclick="document.getElementById('<%=btn_login.ClientID%>').click();">Login</button>
```

Also, you need to make sure your function `checkfields returns true` only then the server side code would be called

```
function checkfields(){

//do you stuff
if (all good){ 
return true;
}
else{// to prevent postback
return false;
}
}
```